# Why is my Catch block only running while Debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0

Code in Program.cs

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    try
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Blah...");
    }
}
```

In Form1 I have a button with the code `throw new Exception("");`.

If I run the application from Visual Studio, then my messagebox pops up (with message 'Blah...'). But if I run the application from executable file, then the catch block doesn't execute at all.

Why the difference?

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, Windows XP.

Comment: What does happen when running outside VS? What happens if you press Ctrl+F5? (Run without debugging)

Comment: Short, incomplete answer:  Stuff happens differently while debugging.  See this question for what you *should* be doing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601372/is-try-catch-around-whole-c-program-possible

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because the standard exception handling for a Windows Forms application behaves differently when the Visual Studio debugger is attached - normally the exception handler built into the `Application.Run` method catches unhandled exceptions so that it can do things like show the following dialog:

[image: Error dialog]

If it allowed the exception to be thrown outside of the `Application.Run` method then it would prevent the application from continuing if the user presses "continue" (as the catch is outside of the message pump).

When debugging however this is disabled, presumably so that the debugger will jump straight into debugging mode on an unhandled exception rather than the above dialog being shown.

If you wish to handle unhandled exceptions in your Windows Forms application then you should handle the [`Application.ThreadException` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx).  Alternatively you can alter this behaviour with the [`Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx#Y600).

You are by no means alone in being confused by this:

- [Is try/catch around whole C# program possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601372/is-try-catch-around-whole-c-program-possible)
- [Exception handling problem in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936947/exception-handling-problem-in-release-mode) (this question is misleadingly named - this isn't related to the Release / Debug build setting)
- [C# Exceptions only caught when debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113755/c-exceptions-only-caught-when-debugging)

Answer (score -1):

Because in **RELEASE** mode at the moment the message box have to be shown yuo're appication is going to be "dead" and you can not stop it by showing MessageBox. In **DEBUG** mode VS cares about that and **breaks** on the line that  throws an exception.

Regards.

Comment: @Slaks: What is the mistake here ?

Comment: Everything.  No part of your answer is true.

Comment: Sorry guys, but the question here is not WHAT he should doing, but why the message box doesn't show in RELEASE by having THIS  code. If you have complete accurate answer to this, I will be only happy to read it. Regards.

Comment: @Slaks: with all respect, but explain at least why. Or Add an answer so people can understand.

Comment: 1) He isn't running Release mode.  2) `catch` blocks work fine in release mode  3) VS isn't breaking in debug mode; he's seeing the MessageBox 4) The actual problem is the default unhandled exception handler, which doesn't run when the debugger is attached.

Comment: @Slaks: by saying RELEASE I mean running RELEASE binaries. Ok I will update my post.

Comment: I know.  He **isn't** running Release binaries.  That doesn't make your answer any less wrong.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But, honestly it's impossible, and potentially possible only in case if it run RELEASE, at least makes some difference :) Regards.

Comment: Also - it doesn't matter if it is compiled in debug or release mode, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @sven: it clearly does, it's enough to try it in the code. cause the question is about message box. try it,and only after downvote.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see why this is happening but try rebuilding the solution, if in doubt I always do that. It may or may not fix the problem and you probably have already tried but if you haven't it may fix it for you.